# Schedule a task every hour to fetch data from Bluetooth device and send it to server.

Tags: android

I have a requirement where i have to send some data to server every hour even in doze mode, active mode or sleep mode. Work manager document says that it respects doze mode. I just want to know is there any way i can achieve this ?

Minsdkversion is 21.
Support china store. 
Want to support OS 8 and 9 too.

What is setRequiresDeviceIdle(true) constraint in workmanager ? Does it works only in doze mode ?

Any other way apart from WorkManager i can achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, the only way that I know of to ensure that your application will send a notification at the right time, 100% of the time, is using [AlarmManager - Alarm Clock](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setAlarmClock(android.app.AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Otherwise, AlarmManager setExactAndAllowWhileIdle (as of API 27) will not always work in doze mode. Same thing with WorkManager. Basically, you'll need to create your Worker and set an AlarmClock within it to start the Worker up again in an hour. The caveat is that this behaves as you'd expect with an AlarmClock, noises, vibrations, etc.